# Will store eggs turn into a chick if i leave it out in the warmth?

Tags: eggs

I want a baby chick and i was wondering if i could leave a store egg our in the summer's warmth/ a warm place and let it turn into a baby chick.. does it really work???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. In most (all?) places that sell chicken eggs in quantity, the eggs are not fertile. For that, there needs to be a rooster involved. The hen that laid your egg doesn't hang out with roosters.

Your best bet is to acquire a few fertilized eggs from a farmer who keeps chickens. You can also buy fertilized eggs online, just search for "fertilized chicken eggs for sale".

Comment: A local farm is the best bet. The eggs bought online may or may not be in condition to give you a chick. Also, the O.P. needs to have the right conditions for the egg to develop.

Comment: More info: modern egg production lines have a "candling station" to see if a fertilized egg is about to be packaged. It is unlikely for a fertilized egg to be created, and it is even more unlikely that fertilized egg would make it past the candling station quality control.